# connect to mapped network drive OSX vmware fusion running windows 7

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-fusion

My setup is as follows.

I have a mac running vmware fusion 7, where I virtualize windows 7. I want to connect to a network drive on my virtual machine instead of needing to connect to it on my mac and then transfer the files from the mac to the virtual machine. It's an unnecessary extra step. Does anyone know how to do this? When I try to map the network drive on the virutal machine it won't accept my credentials.